# Lwuit class not found error.Please help me to solve it?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, mobile-application, midp-2.0, cldc

Im very new to "LWUIT" for "J2ME". I installed eclipse pulsar in my system.I also installed sony ericsson j2me sdk. The normal j2me is works fine.

When I use lwuit in my j2me project. Then it will not working.

I'm creating new project namely "lwuit2" in my eclipse pulsar.

Then I select my project from project or package explorer, then right clickt

Then I click libraries  tab, then I click add external jar button,

then I choose the lwuit path where I store the lwuit.jar

then I click ok. It is success.

the following are my source code

```
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDlet;
import javax.microedition.midlet.MIDletStateChangeException;

import com.sun.lwuit.Display;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;

public class TestMidlet1 extends MIDlet {

    Form frm=null;

    public TestMidlet1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void destroyApp(boolean arg0) throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void pauseApp() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    protected void startApp() throws MIDletStateChangeException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Display.init(this);
        frm=new Form("Testing lwuit");
        frm.show();


    }
}
```

When I type the above code the eclipse pulsar does not shows any compile time error. But when I run it, then it shows the error. I print screen the error window and attached it please refer the attachment below.

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between this question and your previous one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11046661/lwuit-j2me-clas-not-found-error-help-me-to-solve-it

Comment: SORRY BY MISTAKE I POST IT AGAIN.DONT MISTAKE Me gnat.Im in little confustion due to pressure in my office.So i post it again due to confusion.Forgive my mistakes pls gnat.

Comment: then, just delete the question that has been posted by mistake - to avoid readers confusion choosing which one to answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pulsar does not export the lwuit.jar into your midlet's jar unless you instruct it to explicitly. On the "Order and Export" tab of the project's "Java Build Properties" select the lwuit.jar so that it is exported as part of your midlet.